# How to create multiple list item in single list view from JSON in Android

Tags: android, json, listview

How to create a group of list view from JSON in Android. The design of image is given below. That's the way of creation in android.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to what is called as **Header List view** or **Sectioned List view**.
It is always a good idea to use what is already there and not to re-create the wheel. 
To make header list view you can use this library :

https://github.com/applidium/HeaderListView

Demo is included in the repository.

Comment: i am using eclipse so i need of full solution in eclipse please help me.